# Should I fetch data from my database, an open api, or JSON files?

Tags: reactjs, json, next.js

So I am making a Pokemon team builder app for my beginner portfolio. There are over 800+ Pokemon, each with their own unique abilities and moves etc. There exists a free online api called PokeAPI that has all the JSON data I need (a lot more than needed).

I am using NextJS.

I start to wonder if instead I should

- Somehow store the data for each Pokemon in JSON files somewhere in my project directory and fetch the data from the files each time
- or store all the data for each Pokemon in my Mongo database and query my database for each pokemon request
- or stick to the api?

Comment: easier and safer to store in DB, what does it even mean stick to API?

Comment: I think he means API as network calls.

Comment: Is the data static and small enough to reasonably fit in memory? If so (typical pokemon datasets are), store in a variable in your source code. If you expect the data to change and want to get the latest data at the time the app is run, use the API (unless you plan to maintain the dataset).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding on to what jsejcksn said, if you don't need to store the pokemon data from the api then you dont need a database. I doubt the data associated to those pokemon will change (pikachu will still be pikachu in 5 years) so technically you could just fetch the entire list at once and store it in a JSON file. The problem with storing the entire Pokemon data in a JSON file is mainly going to be querying. Storing the information in a database allows you to organize the data and effortlessly query the data you specifically need, something that will take a lot of work and be ineffiecent with just a JSON file.

But maybe you want to showcase your ability to fetch from an external api since this is a portfolio. The Pokemon API may be good enough to where you can pass it very specific parameters and have it return exactly what you want (in essence querying a database that's not maintained by yourself).

However, resorting to just the Pokemon API (and no data storage) does create a dependency on your site, if the Pokemon server goes down, so does your site. They could also change the definition of how to use their API which would mean having to rewrite your code (mainly your fetch call)

Db, JSON file, and just the api call all work in this case, it just depends on how you want to approach the problem.

Comment: Summed it up well. Thank you!

Comment: No problem! If it answered your question, please click the checkmark by the answer to mark it as answered :D